# React button dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-router

In my react application one of the component is creating a button dropdown menu like below.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a onClick=doSomething href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a onClick=doSomething href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a onClick=doSomething href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Questions:

1. Giving href as # on anchor tag changes the url by appending #. If href is not given then hand click icon is not seen on menu while hovering over it. I don't want to change the URL and at the same time I want the hand icon to come on the dropdown menu.
2. Can I prevent default href behavior by some method like preventDefault or something similar?
3. Should I use button from react-bootstrap or this native html button is fine?

Comment: Try applying this CSS rule to the anchor tags: **cursor: pointer;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS `cursor: pointer;`

```css
li{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <li>JavaScript</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: is there an onclick callback on li?

Comment: at the moment no, just a CSS rule. you can add an `onClick` handler though just like any DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a style for the `<a>` tag and remove your `href` attribute.

```
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```